# Multiple return value and := in go

Tags: go, multiple-return-values

Why is this a valid program?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func giveMeError(limit int) ([]string, error) {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("MY ERROR %d", limit)
}

func main() {

    res1, err := giveMeError(1)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("res", res1)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }

    res2, err := giveMeError(5)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("res", res2)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }

}
```

And this isn't?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func giveMeError(limit int) ([]string, error) {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("MY ERROR %d", limit)
}

func main() {

    res, err := giveMeError(1)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("res", res)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }

    res, err := giveMeError(5)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("res", res)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }

}
```

Complains that `./main.go:18: no new variables on left side of :=`

I thought `:=` cannot be used to change value to existing variables?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#redeclaration) is clear at this point:

> In a := declaration a variable v may appear even if it has already
>   been declared, provided:
>
> this declaration is in the same scope as the existing declaration of v
>   (if v is already declared in an outer scope, the declaration will
>   create a new variable §), the corresponding value in the
>   initialization is assignable to v, and **there is at least one other
>   variable in the declaration that is being declared anew**.

Answer (score 3):

klashxx already answer the question.

There may be something confusing here.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
     a, b := 1, 2            
     fmt.Println(a, b)
     {
         b, c := 100, 200       //NOTE: b here is a new variable
         fmt.Println(a, b, c)
     }

     fmt.Println(a, b)

     b, c := 1000, 2000
     fmt.Println(a, b, c)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that at least one of the variables on the left hand side have to be new. You'll commonly see code that reuses the `error` variable when doing one function call after another.

In your second example you're reassigning both values so in a case like that you have to use `=` on subsequent assignment. That particular detail is one you have have to reason about very often in Go. You get used to it quickly though, it's pretty straight forward.